# Why does git not ignore this particular __pycache__ directory?

Tags: git

**INFORMATION**

I made a commit today that failed:

```
git commit backend/projects/* -m "My message"
error: pathspec 'backend/projects/__pycache__' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

The commit included changes to files in subfolders that ALSO include their own `__pycache__` directories, ie. I have a directory structure that looks like this:

```
backend/projects/__pycache__
backend/projects/my_altered_file_1.py
backend/projects/myfolder/__pycache__
backend/projects/myfolder/my_altered_file_2.py
```

In my `.gitignore` I have:

```
# Python byte-compiled / optimized / DLL files
__pycache__/
*.py[cod]
*$py.class
```

And doing `ls -al backend/projects/__pycache__` shows nothing but `.pyc` files in that directory, all of which match the `*.py[cod]` statement in `.gitignore`.

Doing:

```
git ls-files | xargs -n 1 dirname | uniq
```

gives me a list of the directories containing git-controlled files, which does NOT include the offending `__pycache__` directory, so I know nothing in there has accidentally been added to git control previously (which would override the `.gitignore`).

**QUESTION(S)**

Why did the commit fail, when the contents of `backend/projects/__pycache` are completely `.gitignore`d??

And why did retrying after deleting JUST the `backend/projects/__pycache__` work fine, *even though there's another `__pycache__` directory in there which was ignored as expected* (if it's going to fail on one, why wouldn't it fail on both)?

Comment: Try running the command without the `*` on the end of the path. Your shell is probably expanding the expression, so that `__pycache__` is explicitly passed to `git commit`.

Comment: try running the regular `git add backend/projects; git commit -m "My message"` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a fine print in [`git help commit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#_description) (emphasis mine):

> DESCRIPTION
> [...]
> 3. by listing files as arguments to the commit command (without --interactive or --patch switch), in which case the commit will ignore changes staged in the index, and instead record the current content of the listed files (***which must already be known to Git***);

I don't know the exact reason why it is implemented that way, I guess that, since specifying a sequence of `<path>...` makes the commit include *exactly these changes* (ignoring the other possibly staged files), it makes sense to have an error when one of the files or directories listed on the command line will actually *not* be part of your commit.

---

As Richard Smith commented:
when you type `git commit backend/projects/* -m "My message"`, the expansion is made by your shell, so git actually receives a command line which says :

```
git commit backend/projects/mymod1 backend/projects/mymod2 \
    backend/projects/myfile.py backend/projects/__pycache__ ...
```

The fix is to simply name the directory:

```
git commit backend/projects/ -m "My message"
```

Note that if you quote your glob string, the expansion will be done by git :

```
git commit "backend/projects/*" -m "My message"
```

this has however other consequences :
`git` will expand this glob to *the list of files known to git* under that directory, so *new* files under `backend/projects/` would *not* be part of your commit.

---

I would recommend, however, to switch to a classical `git add ...; git commit` workflow, mainly because it allows you to :

```
git add ...
<review what you are about to commit>
git commit
```

Comment: edited my answer: I first (incorrectly) stated that if `git` did the expansion it would do the same thing and just skip ignored files, it actually only takes the already tracked files into account and *ignores new files* -- so the end result can be very different from what you intended to do with your shell glob

Comment: I just knew it would be something like that!Thank you LeGEC!

Comment: FYI I don't use git add then commit separately in the way you suggest, because I use precommit to QA and format files - any changes form that would mean I'd have to explicitly stage those changes again which makes for a frustrating workflow.

Comment: ok, fwiw we have set up our repo with a precommit hook which *fails if format doesn't fit* but doesn't edit, and a script which formats our files. Again: that way we can review what we commit. But if you have a working workflow and no weird side effects, go for it.